# Evaluating a function in SymPy with a matrix as input

Tags: python, sympy

I want to make a polynomial in SymPy, but ideally I want to write my code as general as possible:

```
from sympy import *

sx, sa0, sa1, sa2 = symbols('x sa0 sa1 sa2')

sa = MatrixSymbol('a',3,1)

polynomial = sum([sa[i,0]*sx**i/factorial(i) for i in range(sa.shape[0])])
```

The following expression gives the polynomial explicitly but the code is not as general as I would like it to be:

```
poly2 = sx**2*sa2/2 + sx*sa1 + sa0
```

In this expression `sa0`, `sa1`, `sa2` replace `sa[0,0]`, `sa[1,0]`, and `sa[2,0]`, respectively.

My problem is that I can evaluate `poly2` but not 'polynomial':

```
>>> print(poly2.evalf(subs={sx: 10, sa0: 1, sa1: 1, sa2: 1}))
>>> 61.0000000000000
>>> print(polynomial.evalf(subs={sx: 10, sa[0,0]: 1, sa[1,0]: 1, sa[2,0]: 1}))
>>> 0.5*x**2*a[2, 0] + x*a[1, 0] + a[0, 0]
>>> print(polynomial.evalf(subs={sx: 10, sa: [[1, 1, 1]]}))
>>> 0.5*x**2*a[2, 0] + x*a[1, 0] + a[0, 0]
```

How can I insert values of the MatrixSymbol object `sa` in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `xreplace` instead of `evalf`. Ideally `subs` would also work, but it looks like there is a bug.